# How to graph the revolution of solid limited by 2 points in x axis

Tags: plotting

I'm learning how use this program. And I have problem with how graph the solid of revolution.Here i write one exercise.
 y=2-1/2x, y=0,x=1,x=2; about the x-axis. 
This is the graph also the volume [image]

x=1 and x=2 limited the size of the graph and I don't know how do that in Wolfram Mathematica.
 The steps i think are:
RevolutionPlot3d [2-1/2x,{x,0,4},{y,0,4}] ....

Comment: `RevolutionPlot3D[2 - 1/2 x, {x, 1, 2}]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usage is like this.

```
RevolutionPlot3D[2 - x/2, {x, 1, 2},
 RevolutionAxis -> "X", Boxed -> False,
 PlotRange -> {{0, 3}, All, All},
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0},
 Mesh -> {5, 0},
 PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.7]
 ]
```

> [image: Blockquote]

And you can use `Manipulate`.

```
Manipulate[RevolutionPlot3D[2 - x/2, {x, a, b},
  RevolutionAxis -> "X", Boxed -> False,
  PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, All, All},
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0},
  Mesh -> {5, 0},
  PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.7]
  ], {{a, 1}, 0, 2}, {{b, a + 1}, a + 0.01, 4}]
```

> [image: Blockquote]